# Redeem script for segwit addresses

Tags: p2sh, segregated-witness, p2wpkh

How does one derive the Redeem Script for the new Pay-to-Witness Pubkey Hash addresses? With existing P2SH it's revealed after providing N number of Public Keys through a `createmultisig` function in the bitcoin client. Is it the same, just provide a single public key through a `createwitness` or similar function?

Is it currently available for fiddling with on testnet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Feb2018**: an older request, I just answer it so that future research might reveal useful data :-)

To compose the redeem script for a P2WPKH, there is a fairly simple structure, I copied this mostly [from here](https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/#creation-of-p2sh-p2wpkh-address):

Start with OP_0, followed by the keyhash. Keyhash is calculated with  RIPEMD160(SHA256(public key)), similiar to "std" PKH. Do not use uncompressed pubkeys!

The P2SH redeemScript will then always have 22 bytes:

```
OP_0:    00
Length:  14
keyhash: (20 bytes)
```

The scriptPubKey is composed this way:

```
OP_HASH160 hash160(redeemScript) OP_EQUAL
```

and the address is the corresponding P2SH address with prefix 3.

[Step by step explanation](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60961/generate-paper-wallet-segwit-address) here :-)