# Generate paper wallet SegWit address

Tags: segregated-witness, address-generation

I am trying to generate SegWit paper wallet address from WIF:

My WIF is `L5mHKZsCLS27nSoGM3RdAwuxjvg7XhJdP25LgqdXe6zF11wpWdbT`.

I am converting WIF to compressed public key:

Compressed public key: `03fac6879502c4c939cfaadc45999c7ed7366203ad523ab83ad5502c71621a85bb`

I am creating P2SH-P2WPKH address using instructions at [Creation of P2SH-P2WPKH Address](https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/)

using following algorithm:

1. Calculate the RIPEMD160 of the SHA256 of a public key:

SHA256 of public key: `cfad24b0bc2bba2c8bb2c8d619dca2b74221930793bca50df73856f0bbba10c9`

RIPEMD160 of SHA256 hash: `d5e5d05edfe2ed61099bf3f0d53be2775bbc6d0d`

2. Create P2SH redeemScript as `OP_PUSH publicKeyHash`:

redeemScript: `0014d5e5d05edfe2ed61099bf3f0d53be2775bbc6d0d`

3. Generate scriptPubKey as `OP_HASH160 hash160(redeemScript) OP_EQUAL`

scriptPubKey: `a914a19949e546c2f4d410cbb061c986b9ff3099ae7087`

4. Generate RIPEMD160 hash of scriptPubKey:

hash: `dc62e525af22d1f0f17cc2a091cf2c9fb36bf553`

5. Generate address with `0x05` prefix and double SHA256 hash checksum:

result: `3MnK46gvixm8hk7mJTQTAqenniSodjXPrJ`

Expected result according to [segwitaddress](https://segwitaddress.org) is:

`33voQqbNAYyig272KjcX8GkucWn2x25WEg`

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Thanks to the accepted answer, here are correct steps to do this:

```
Public key - compressed: 
03fac6879502c4c939cfaadc45999c7ed7366203ad523ab83ad5502c71621a85bb

SHA256(public key) =
cfad24b0bc2bba2c8bb2c8d619dca2b74221930793bca50df73856f0bbba10c9

RIPEMD160(SHA256(public key)) =
7646c030f7e75b80f0a31cdcab731e6f424f22b2

redeemScript (OP_0 pubkeyHash160):
00147646c030f7e75b80f0a31cdcab731e6f424f22b2

SHA256(redeemScript) =
a10e523968ba784d24ccd54e613d8f747d6649e42b1df4fdcec6658262620651

RIPEMD160(SHA256(redeemScript)) =
188ba16284702258959d8bb63bb9a5d979b57875

P2SH address base58(0x05 | hash | 4-byte sha256 checksum) =
33voQqbNAYyig272KjcX8GkucWn2x25WEg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2. Create P2SH redeemScript as `OP_PUSH publicKeyHash`:
>
> redeemScript: `0014d5e5d05edfe2ed61099bf3f0d53be2775bbc6d0d`

It's actually `OP_0  but you have resulted in the right thing anyways.

> 3. Generate scriptPubKey as `OP_HASH160 hash160(redeemScript) OP_EQUAL`
>
> scriptPubKey: `a914a19949e546c2f4d410cbb061c986b9ff3099ae7087`
>
> 4. Generate RIPEMD160 hash of scriptPubKey:
>
> hash: `dc62e525af22d1f0f17cc2a091cf2c9fb36bf553`

These steps are incorrect. The thing that is hashed for a P2SH address is the redeemScript, not the scriptPubKey. Instead of doing step 3, you would skip directly to step 4 and hash the redeemScript instead of the scriptPubKey.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I was hoping you could help. I think I'm not generating the checksum correctly. Before the base58 encoding, this is the string I have: 05188ba16284702258959d8bb63bb9a5d979b5787555c30444. After base58 that's 33voQqbNAYyig272KjcX8GkucWn2uJk5WT. Last 6 characters are incorrect. Which part am I getting wrong?

Comment: @user2298995 Your checksum is wrong. The hex should be 05188BA16284702258959D8BB63BB9A5D979B57875BFE2FCFD

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment!  How is the checksum generated then? I took the 4 bytes of sha256(sha256(redeemScript)). Is it not the proper way?

Comment: No, it is the first 4 bytes of the sha256(sha256(payload)) where the payload is the data you are encoding with the base58 check encoding. In this case, the payload is 05188BA16284702258959D8BB63BB9A5D979B57875

Comment: Oh thank you very much. Very appreciated!